# golang reading a large number using bufio.NewScanner

Tags: go

I tried to get the input (many number with space) and converted it to slice.
number of numbers is up to 300,000

I got an error and I googled it. and there's some problem with buffer size.
so I wrote the code as below.

```
func ChangeToInt(input string) []int {
    var nums []int
    for _, word := range strings.Fields(input) {
        num, _ := strconv.Atoi(word)
        nums = append(nums, num)
    }
    return nums
}

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

maxCapacity := 4*300000
buf := make([]byte, maxCapacity)
scanner.Buffer(buf, maxCapacity)

scanner.Scan()
input := scanner.Text()
nums := ChangeToInt(input)
```

but still not working. what's the problem?

Comment: `what's the problem?` good question.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What error do you get, if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) to read your input. By default `bufio.Scanner` reads lines, and it uses an internal buffer to store the line. By default the line may have a max length of [`bufio.MaxScanTokenSize`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#MaxScanTokenSize) which is 64 KB. If your lines are longer than this, you'll get an error.

The internal buffer size may be changed / increased using the [`Scanner.Buffer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Buffer) method, but if your input is a space separated list of numbers, I'd advise to change the split function of the `Scanner`.

As mentioned earlier, by default the scanner splits input by *lines*. Instead change it to split the input by *words*. The [`bufio`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/) package has a "ready" split function for that: [`bufio.Scanwords`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanWords). Use it like this:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
```

Now the [`scanner.Text()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Text) will return the words (numbers in your case) instead of complete lines, so the default 64 KB limit now applies to words, not lines. Your numbers should be less than 64 KB.

Also do check if scanning succeeds by calling [`scanner.Err()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Err).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bufio.NewReader` and its `ReadString('\n')` method. It will be good for large input data.